# Debugging <<loop>> error message in haskell

Tags: debugging, haskell

Hello i am encountering this error message in a Haskell program and i do not know where is the loop coming from.There are almost no `IO` methods so that i can hook myself to them and print the partial result in the terminal.

I start with a file , i read it and then there are only pure methods.How can i debug this ?

Is there a way to attach to methods or create a helper that can do the following:

Having a method `method::a->b` how can i somehow wrap it in a `iomethod::(a->b)->IO (a->b)` to be able to test in in `GHCI` (i want to insert some `putStrLn`-s etc ?

**P.S** My data suffer transformations `IO a(->b->c->d->......)->IO x` and i do not know how to debug the part that is in the parathesis (that is the code that contains the pure methods)

**Types and typeclass definitions and implementations**

```
data TCPFile=Rfile (Maybe Readme) | Dfile  Samples | Empty
data Header=Header { ftype::Char}

newtype Samples=Samples{values::[Maybe Double]}deriving(Show)

data Readme=Readme{ maxClients::Int, minClients::Int,stepClients::Int,maxDelay::Int,minDelay::Int,stepDelay::Int}deriving(Show)

data FileData=FileData{ header::Header,rawContent::Text}

(>>?)::Maybe a->(a->Maybe b)->Maybe b
(Just t) >>? f=f t
Nothing >>? _=Nothing

class TextEncode a where
fromText::Text-> a


getHeader::TCPFile->Header
getHeader (Rfile _ ) = Header { ftype='r'}
getHeader (Dfile _ )= Header{ftype='d'}
getHeader _ = Header {ftype='e'}


instance Show TCPFile where
show (Rfile t)="Rfile " ++"{"++content++"}" where
    content=case t of
        Nothing->""
        Just c -> show c
show (Dfile c)="Dfile " ++"{"++show c ++ "}"

instance TextEncode Samples where
    fromText text=Samples  (map (readMaybe.unpack) cols) where
             cols=splitOn (pack ",") text



instance TextEncode Readme where
    fromText txt =let len= length dat
                      dat= case len of 
                            6 ->Prelude.take 6 .readData $ txt
                            _ ->[0,0,0,0,0,0] in 
            Readme{maxClients=Prelude.head dat,minClients=dat!!1,stepClients=dat!!2,maxDelay=dat!!3,minDelay=dat!!4,stepDelay=dat!!5} where




instance TextEncode TCPFile where
    fromText  = textToFile
```

**Main**

```
module Main where 
import Data.Text(Text,pack,unpack)
import Data.Text.IO(readFile,writeFile)
import TCPFile(TCPFile)

main::IO()
main=do
    dat<-readTcpFile "test.txt"
    print dat

readTcpFile::FilePath->IO TCPFile
readTcpFile path =fromText <$> Data.Text.IO.readFile path  

textToFile::Text->TCPFile
textToFile input=case readHeader input >>? (\h -> Just (FileData h input)) >>?  makeFile of
    Just r -> r
    Nothing ->Empty



readHeader::Text->Maybe Header
readHeader txt=case Data.Text.head txt of 
    'r' ->Just (Header{ ftype='r'})
    'd' ->Just (Header {ftype ='d'})
    _  -> Nothing

makeFile::FileData->Maybe TCPFile
makeFile fd= case ftype.header $ fd of
        'r'->Just (Rfile (Just (fromText . rawContent $ fd)))
        'd'->Just (Dfile (fromText . rawContent $ fd))
        _  ->Nothing 


readData::Text->[Int]
readData =catMaybes . maybeValues where
    maybeValues=mvalues.split.filterText "{}"

#all the methods under this line  are used in the above method

mvalues::[Text]->[Maybe Int]
mvalues arr=map (\x->(readMaybe::String->Maybe Int).unpack $ x) arr

split::Text->[Text]
split =splitOn (pack ",")

filterText::[Char]->Text->Text
filterText chars tx=Data.Text.filter (\x -> not (x `elem` chars)) tx
```

I want first to clean the `Text` from given characters , in our case `}{` then split it by `,`.After the text is split by commas i want to parse them, and create either a `Rfile` which contains `6` integers , either a `Dfile` (datafile) which contains any given number of integers.

**Input**
I have a file with the following content: `r,1.22,3.45,6.66,5.55,6.33,2.32}` and i am running `runghc main 2>err.hs`

**Expected Output** : `Rfile (Just (Readme 1.22 3.45 6.66 5.55 6.33 2.32))`

Comment: Please share the relevant code

Comment: You could try using `Debug.Trace` for printf like debugging without needing to `IO` everything.

Comment: I have added the code..but i don't think it helps .

Comment: Your code is difficult to read because the formatting is difficult and inconsistent; you have lots of functions that don’t seem to make sense; incomplete instances; and it is so disorganised that it is not clear what is supposed to happen. I don’t see an obvious place where you get the error. Another thing you could try is running/testing small parts in ghci.

Comment: I have mentioned just a mehtod of the instance , the one that matters.Sorry for the indentation i will clean it.

Comment: You don't need to define `>>?`; you can use `>>=` directly.

Comment: To debug this kind of thing, other than staring at the code, one thing you can do is compile with `-prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts`, and run your program with the cmd line options `+RTS -xc`. This should print a trace when the `<<loop>>` exception is raised (or if the program loops instead, when you kill it (Ctrl+C)). See the GHC manual https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-flag--xc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `TextEncode Readme` instance, `len` and `dat` depend on each other:

```
instance TextEncode Readme where
    fromText txt =let len= length dat
                      dat= case len of
```

---

To debug this kind of thing, other than staring at the code, one thing you can do is compile with `-prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts`, and run your program with the cmd line options `+RTS -xc`. This should print a trace when the `<<loop>>` exception is raised (or if the program loops instead, when you kill it (Ctrl+C)). See the GHC manual https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-flag--xc

Answer (score 2):

As Li-yao Xia  said part of the problem is the infinite recursion, but if you tried the following code, then the problem still remains.

```
instance TextEncode Readme where
    fromText txt =let len= length [1,2,3,4,5,6] --dat
                      dat= case len of
```

The second issue is that the file contains decimal numbers but all the conversion function are expecting `Maybe Int`, changing the definitions of the following functions should give the expected results, on the other hand probably the correct fix is that the file should have integers and not decimal numbers.

```
readData::Text->[Double]
--readData xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6]
readData =catMaybes . maybeValues where
    maybeValues = mvalues . split . filterText "{}"

--all the methods under this line  are used in the above method

mvalues::[Text]->[Maybe Double]
mvalues arr=map (\x->(readMaybe::String->Maybe Double).unpack $ x) arr

data Readme=Readme{ maxClients::Double, minClients::Double,stepClients::Double,maxDelay::Double,minDelay::Double,stepDelay::Double}deriving(Show)
```